# Возвращение на предыдущую страницу в react router dom 6

Tags: reactjs

Вопрос простой, как вернуться на предыдущую страницу после авторизации? Например, пользователь перешел на /account/something и его перекинуло на /account/auth. Как сделать так чтобы после авторизации на /account/auth он возвращался на /account/something?

P.S. Авторизация проверяется наличием определенного контекста.

Comment: через query надо указать перед редиректом на /account/auth

Comment: http://localhost:3000/account/auth?next=/account/something например

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119793/react-router-redirection-after-login

Answer (score 0):

Mожно использовать хук [`useNavigate()`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate).